# To change user agent back to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-agent

i was trying to change the user agent in chrome to Ipad and android settings using user-Agent switcher in chrome.

Now i selected back Chrome Default but still my screen size looks like ipad. how do i reset it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's back to defaults? You can confirm using http://whatsmyuseragent.com or similar sites. Did you close and reopen Chrome and test?

Comment: its showing Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.17 Safari/537.11

Comment: That looks like Chrome user-agent to me. Clear cache. Maybe the site you're visiting, cached your device type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press F12 to open Developer tools in Google Chrome.
2. Open Settings
3. Check if **Device Metrics** checkbox is ticked.